# Eigenvectors as basis for given matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

suppose i have given some quadratic matrix,which i have  represented as a  multiplication of two orthogonal matrices and one diagonal matrix,for example

A =

```
 3     2     4
 1     2     4
 0    10    21



[E D,V]=svd(A)

E =

   -0.1892    0.9302    0.3145
   -0.1866    0.2803   -0.9416
   -0.9640   -0.2369    0.1206


D =

   24.1153         0         0
         0    3.0743         0
         0         0    0.0540


V =

   -0.0313    0.9989    0.0339
   -0.4309    0.0171   -0.9022
   -0.9018   -0.0428    0.4299
```

as i know $E$ and $V$ matrices are orthogonal,because it's columns are orthogonal,also as i know orthogonality  implies linear independence  of these vectors,could  i have considered these vectors separately as a basis?or maybe  list of vectors  from $E$ and $V$  as basis,which means that can i use these vectors together to  get original matrix using some combinations?thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. The columns of **any** invertible matrix can be used as a basis.

Comment: of course if they are independent w right?

Comment: The matrix is invertible **iff** they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we name the singular values as $d_1,d_2,d_3$, the columns of $E$ as $e_1,e_2,e_3$, and the rows of $V$ as $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Then the singular value decomposition tells you precisely that $A$ is the operator given by
$$
Av_j=d_je_j.
$$

Comment: so  what does it means  in algebraic terms?

Comment: in this case  $d_1$,$d_2$ and $d_3$  is a singular values right ?and $e_1$,..$e_3$ and $v_1$,..$v_3$ as a eigenvectors right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "algebraic terms". Yes, the $d_j$ are the singular values. And no, they would only be eigenvectors if $v_j=e_j$.

Comment: then i did not understand meaning of what  you have written,can you explain me in detail?

Comment: i mean does it answer to me if Eigenvectors could be basis?

Comment: The eigenvectors will be a basis precisely with $d_j\ne0$ for all $j$. But you are looking at the SVD, not diagonalization. If $A$ is not positive-definite, then the SVD may have no relation at all with the eigenvectors of the original $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the column vectors in $E$ as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Similarly, the vectors in $V$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. But, it is meaningless to say that vectors in $E$ and $V$ can be used as a basis to get the matrix back. If you are looking for a basis for the matrix, then you are looking at an entirely different vector space. You need a set of matrices, who linear combination can then be used to get the original matrix back. Also, it should span the set of all $3\times 3$ real matrices. In that case, the vector space of $3\times 3$ matrices is a 9-dimensional space. SVD is not a decomposition of the matrix into a linear combination of matrices, but rather it gives a product decomposition. Having said that, note that 
\begin{align}
A=\sum_{j=1}^{r}d_j(e_jv_j^T)
\end{align} 
(verify this yourself). Thus SVD indeed gives the matrix $A$ as a linear combination of some rank-one matrices ($e_jv_j^T$) with the weights being the singular values. But this rank-one matrices, will never be a basis for the whole $3\times 3$ matrices in general.

Comment: but in generally it gives as a basis right to get another matrix,not original

Comment: Just so that you can get another matrix using yet another linear combination doesn't guarantee it is a basis.

Comment: I think you are confusing between linear combination of matrices and linear combination of vectors. Linear combination of vectors gives vectors of same dimension.

Comment: but we can construct matrix  suing these vectors right?

Comment: No, you can't. If you are looking at a basis for a $3\times 3$ matrix, then you are looking at a different vector space. You need a set of matrices which will sum to the matrix in question. A set of vectors can never be linearly combined to give a matrix!!!

Comment: i understood thanks in advance